# Cannot login to Azure BeC account with Connect-MSOL with some directories

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to log into my B2C domain with a local global admin account.

I have tried creating three different accounts with different passwords and still get a incorrect username or password 
Tried

Connect-MsolService

entered username and password

username is a "local" AD domain

so my my directory name is contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com

so user is bob.murray@contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com 
password is easy to type and still get

```
    Connect-MsolService : The user name or password is incorrect. Verify your user name, and then type your password again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80048821,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Tried multiple users, copied and pasted password from text file and logged into portal at same time and I still get the same error

Any help would be great as I am trying to enable groups through doc

```
t.co/krStaURSoF
```

Screenshot of login failure 
[image: Failure to login]

---

I have just tried creating a brand new B2C tenant and in my new tenant i am having the exact same problem , i am creating my B2C tenant through the old portal, is this still a valid way to create B2C tenants ?

Comment: I believe you need to sign in vie the portal first with the newly created user and THEN you should be able to sign in through PowerShell.

Comment: Hey, no , tried that, and got the same issue, because when i created the user i got a temp password, i needed to log into the portal to change the password;

Comment: I dont think any user of my b2c domain can log in, i have other b2c domains that allow powershell to log in

Comment: With the new Azure shell built in the portal released today i cant use it as it says i dont have a subscription associated with the domain, could it be this that is preventing Msol from connecting ?

Comment: Having an Azure subscription isn't a pre-requisite for the Msol commands to work. What about just running Connect-MsolService (without passing in a credential) and signing in via the Azure AD prompt (instead of the Get-Credentail) approach.

Comment: Same, username and password issue  after, password definetly correct ,

Comment: Can you edit your post with a screenshot of the interactive login screen with the error message please.

Comment: You have an old version of the MSOL commandlets, I'd recommend reinstalling both the Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant and the 64-bit Azure Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell. You're screenshot look like an actual Azure Active Directory sign-in page.

Comment: Ok will try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Saca's comment was correct i had an older verison of Connect-MSol Upgraded it , logged in fine and it all worked